When Americans use the word "theater" by itself, how do they know if they are referring to movies or live stage performances?
I noticed that in USA, people say "movies", movie theater, or just theater when referring to the place to watch movies and never "cinema" in a verbal conversation. However, the first is only used in reference of someone or something being there. In written language, theater is used for the cinema while "theatre" is still used for live-stage performances.
Now, the question is, how do people know which they refer to?
Weird thing is some cinema places in USA use the word "cinema" instead of "theater", such as Regal Cinemas. The C in AMC stands for "Cinema" too, and Century uses Cinemark, so I am sure Americans will know cinema relates to movies.
Also, when they say "at the movies", isnt it kind of weird cause you would be only seeing one movie at a time, not 2 at once?

Saying 'at the movies' must be a survival of the time when cinemas normally showed a rolling programme of two feature films plus a news film. In the UK we used to say 'at the pictures' or 'the flicks'.

Do people there say "pictures" or "flicks" more than cinema? In Australia, neither flicks nor pictures is used when talking about the cinema or movies.

@Megas "The Pcitures" is a very common phrase in the UK. I'd argue that "The flicks" is very out-dated.

I said we used to say. Yes, @SiHa, 'the flicks' is old-fashioned slang. Nowadays we 'go to the cinema' or 'go to see a film'.

Same way they understand anything else that has more than one meaning. See chips/fries, stand, suppose, sanction...

Core answer: No one uses one word "by itself." Meaning is created by context.

Why three downvotes? And in my opinion a close-vote with the "use a dictionary" reason doesn't make sense. The OP clearly knows the dictionary definitions of all these words and is asking about regional variation, which is hard to pin down.

Yes, the word "theater" can mean either a place to watch movies or a place to watch a stage play. It can also mean a place to hear a live concert or watch a stand-up comic or pretty much any place where an audience might go to watch some sort of "show". If it's not obvious from context, we add some words to make clear. Like, "I went to the movie theater" or "I went to a theater to watch a play".
"Theatre" is just the British spelling of "theater". Americans sometimes use it to look more "continental". But it is absolutely NOT true that "theatre" means a place to watch a stage play and "theater" is a place to watch a movie. Both are a "theater" in normal use, a "theatre" if someone is trying to be pretentious.
Americans recognize the word "cinema" but rarely use it. A movie theater may call itself the something-something-cinema just to sound fancier than calling it a theater, or to add some variety. If I heard someone say, "I am going to the cinema", I would know what he meant but I'd think it an odd word to use.
It's not really mysterious that one word can mean several different kind of places. They're all related: they are all places where an audience goes to watch a performance. And we often use general words like that. If someone says, "I just got a new pet", "pet" doesn't tell us whether it's a dog or a cat or an iguana or whatever. Or if someone says "I'm going to the store", that doesn't tell us whether it is a shoe store or a hardware store or a grocery store. If it's relevant, he'd have to add some words to specify. Surely your native language has some general words like that.
Years ago I had a conversation with someone from India who told me that in his native language, there is no word corresponding to the English word "grandparent". He said that they have a word for father's father and a word for father's mother and a word for mother's father and a word for mother's mother, but no word that can mean any of the four. I asked him, if you wanted to ask, "Do any of your grandparents have heart disease?" -- perhaps on a medical questionnaire -- how would you say that then? He replied that you would have to say the equivalent of, "Does your father's father, your father's mother, your mother's father, or your mother's mother have heart disease?" (Seems awkward to me. He insisted it proved that Indians value family more than Americans because they have more words for family relationships. Whatever.)

Is the New Yorker, then, 'pretentious'?

I actually use "cinema" regularly to mean "multiplex." I used it in a google maps search just yesterday when I found that "movies" was giving me too many Redbox rental locations. Also: In the US I find the spelling "theatre" so prevalently substituted that it almost doesn't count as a regional distinction any more (like "grey").

@MichaelHarvey Uhhhhh well, it's the New Yorker..... so...

@AndyBonner-it's my favourite American periodical. I think it's just fine.

@MichaelHarvey The New Yorker is very proud of being pretentious. They are the epitome of pretentiousness. :-)

Pretentiousness is an unwarranted claim to importance or distinction; the New Yorker may fairly lay claim to both these qualities. I like Harper's as well, but I think the New Yorker has the better cartoons. I see Harper's has a little piece about an Italian TV ad for potato chips in which nuns are shown eating them in a mock sacrament. A list of comments published in various places about this is headed 'Body of Crisp'. This I like.

@MichaelHarvey Your final sentence "This I like" seems incorrect to me. Why didn't you say "I like this"? Why is it possible to put the direct object "this" of the verb "like" in front of the whole sentence? Thanks.

It's called 'inversion for emphasis' and 'this I like' is often seen or heard in English.

@MichaelHarvey I was being snide. If you want a more literal statement, I would say, The New Yorker supposes itself to be very prestigious, and uses language that could be considered either very formal and elite, or very pretentious, depending on one's viewpoint.

OK - that's fair enough. My 'viewpoint' is that the language used by the New Yorker is clear, elegant, and not 'dumbed down'. It's not the New York Post, that's for sure. Is that 'elitist'?
